# Spring Boot/Data: Generic service class for crud operations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I want to create a REST API which performs basic CRUD operations on several entities. For that I've created generic interface:

```
public interface CrudService<T>{
    //generic CRUD methods
}
```

And its implementation for `Foo` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
}

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>{
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class FooCrudServiceImpl implements CrudService{

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository repository;

    //CRUD methods implementation
}

@RestController
class FooController{
    @Autowired
    private CrudService<Foo> crudService;

    //Controller methods
}
```

What I want to avoid now is creating service implementation for each entity  with basically the same logic. So I tried to create a generic service class which can be called from multiple controllers(FooController, BarController etc.):

```
@Service
@Transactional
class GenericCrudServiceImpl<T> implements CrudService{

    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<T, Long> repository;

    //generic CRUD methods implementation
}
```

and pass that service class to each controller where the entity type would be specified. The problem is that there will be multiple repository beans that could be injected into `GenericCrudServiceImpl` (FooRepository, BarRepository etc.) and just by specifying the type of `JpaRepository` Spring still doesn't know which bean to inject. I don't want to call repository beans directly from controller classes to maintain seperation of responsibilities.

Additionally, for some reason this problem doesn't occur on controller level where I inject `CrudService` interface and Spring understands which bean should it choose, which messes with my whole understanding of dependency injection.

**Is there a way to create such a generic service class?** Other posts on stackoverflow didn't provide me with an answer.

Bonus question: what's the difference between using a @Qualifier annotation and  injecting a specific implementation (in this example `FooCrudServiceImpl` instead of `CrudService` in controller class)? In both cases pointing to different use implementation requires changing one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

What about that:

```
@Transactional
public class GenericCrudServiceImpl<T> implements CrudService{
   private JpaRepository<T, Long> repository;

   public GenericCrudServiceImpl(JpaRepository<T, Long> repository) {
      this.repository = repository;
   }
}
```

And Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public PersistanceConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public JpaRepository<Foo, Long> fooJpaRepository() {
      ...
   }

   @Bean
   public JpaRepository<Foo, Long> booJpaRepository() {
      ...
   }

   @Bean
   public CrudService<Foo> fooService(JpaRepository<Foo, Long> fooJpaRepository) {
      return new GenericCrudServiceImpl(fooJpaRepository);
   }

   @Bean
   public CrudService<Foo> booService(JpaRepository<Foo, Long> booJpaRepository) {
      return new GenericCrudServiceImpl(booJpaRepository);
   }
}
```

And Controller

```
@RestController
class FooController{
       
   // Injection by bean name 'fooService'
   @Autowired
   private CrudService<Foo> fooService;
    
   //Controller methods
}
```